# Trigger fire on each inserted row to insert into remote Table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, triggers

I have two different SQL 2008 servers, I don't have permission to create a linked server in any of them.
i created a trigger on server1.table1 to insert the same record to the remote server server2.table1 using OPENROWSET

i created a stored procedure to insert this record, and i have no issue when i execute the stored procedure. it insert the recored into the remote server.

the problem is when i call the stored procedure from trigger, i get an error message.

can anyone help me please to solve this issue

## Stored Procedure:

```
USE [DB1]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertIntoRemoteTable]
        @Description nvarchar(50)
        AS

        insert into 
                    OPENROWSET(
                    'SQLNCLI', 'Server=Server2;UID=MySRV2user;PWD=MySRV2Password',
                    'SELECT Description FROM [RemoteDB].[dbo].[Table_1]')
        SELECT @Description
```

## Trigger:

```
    ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[InsertTable1]
   ON  [DB1].[dbo].[Table_1] 
   for insert
AS 

BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @Desc nvarchar(50)
    Select @Desc = i.Descr from INSERTED i;
    EXEC   InsertIntoRemoteTable @Desc
END
```

## When i try to insert a new description value in the table i got the following error message:

```
"No row was updated
the data in row 1 was not committed
Error source .Net SqlClient Data provider.
Error Message: the operation could not be performed because OLE DB
provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "(null)" returned message "The partner transaction manager has disabled its support for remote/network transaction.".

correct the errors entry or press ESC to cancel the change(s).
```

can anyone help please on this 
thanks

Comment: Your trigger has  MAJOR flaw. It assumes there will only ever be a single row inserted. You need to write triggers to handle sets of data. What that most likely means in this case is to modify the procedure InsertIntoRemoteTable to receive a table valued parameter instead of a scalar value. As for the error message...did you try researching it? Searching the error message provides thousands and thousands of links that explain that message and how to fix it.

Comment: I really didn't look closely at your procedure. What is the point of the parameter there? You pass it in and then select it at the end. The other interesting part is you just insert all the rows from Table_1 into the remote table. That is going produce duplicates out the wazoo because it just keeps inserting the same rows over and over. I think you need to analyze your process and figure out what you are trying to do here.

Comment: the parameter is the new inserted fields value, so when new record inserted into the table1 the trigger call the procedure and send the fields value to insert these values into the remote table

Comment: But look at your insert statement. It doesn't get just that row, it gets ALL rows from Table_1. To be honest I don't know why you are using OPENROWSET here at all. Why not just a simple insert directly in your trigger?

Comment: i am not inserting all the row, i am trying to insert only the new inserted record

Comment: But your insert statement has no where clause.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have over complicated this. There is really no need for a stored procedure here to do this. You can do this insert into another database directly in your trigger with a simple insert statement. This removes a ton of complexity and it is set based.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[InsertTable1]
   ON  [DB1].[dbo].[Table_1] 
   for insert
AS 

BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO RemoteDB].[dbo].[Table_1](Description)
    Select i.Descr 
    from INSERTED i;
END
```

Comment: Thank you for the code, your code can work if i have linked server. and i really don't have permission to create a new linked server, this is why i used OPENROWSET to send the server, userID, and password at runtime. thanks again for your help

Comment: one more thing, i am able to execute the procedure and path the parameter, and the record successfully inserted into the remote table. the only thing, when i call it from the trigger, i got this message

Comment: But when you call from your trigger you will get all the rows from Table_1 unless you add a where clause. As I said previously, do a search for your EXACT message and you will be presented with the answer thousands of times.

Comment: no, i only get the inserted value "from INSERTED"

Select @Desc = i.Descr from INSERTED i;

please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: NO. Look at your insert query. "SELECT Description FROM [RemoteDB].[dbo].[Table_1]", you need to add a where clause to that.

Comment: And your trigger still have the flaw of incorrectly assuming that inserted will only ever have a single row.

Comment: do you mean the syntax is not correct to call the procedure from trigger?
if yes, can you send me the correct syntax

Comment: also the table is empty, and i am trying to insert first record

Comment: The syntax is fine but the logic error is that consider what happens when two rows are inserted into Table_1. Which row will be sent to the procedure? Only 1 of them will, not both. If you don't handle multiple row operations in your trigger it is a huge problem. Then you also need to add a where clause in the select statement inside your trigger.

Comment: what i understood id the trigger fire for single insert into the table.
but this is not the case, i am trying to insert single record for test. it successfully insert the record when i execute the procedure, and get the error message when i call the procedure from trigger

Comment: what do you want me to change in the trigger?

where what in case of insert?

the link you provided is not working